# Pointer iteration issue

Tags: rust

I try to iterate pointer from an allocated array.

Consider this example:

```
let layout = Layout::array::<u32>(5).unwrap();

let mut ptr = alloc(layout) as *mut u32;

let base = ptr;

ptr = ptr.add(0);
*ptr = 10;
ptr = ptr.add(1);
*ptr = 100;
ptr = ptr.add(2);
*ptr = 200;
ptr = ptr.add(3);
*ptr = 300;
ptr = ptr.add(4);
*ptr = 400;


let a = *base.add(0);
let b = *base.add(1);
let c = *base.add(2);
let d = *base.add(3);
let e = *base.add(4);
```

result is:

a : 10
b : 100
c : 0
d : 200
e : 0

What did I mistake, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the following values:

- `base.add(0)` via `ptr.add(0)`
- `base.add(1)` via `ptr.add(1)`
- `base.add(3)` via `ptr.add(2)` (on the already modified pointer)
- and so on:

```rust
ptr = ptr.add(0); // total offset =  0
*ptr = 10;
ptr = ptr.add(1); // total offset =  1
*ptr = 100;
ptr = ptr.add(2); // total offset =  3 <--- whoops!
*ptr = 200;
ptr = ptr.add(3); // total offset =  6 <--- undefined behavior!
*ptr = 300;
ptr = ptr.add(4); // total offset = 10 <--- further undefined behavior
*ptr = 400;
```

You either need to keep the original pointer or only use `ptr.add(1)` to advance to the next location.